# Where to get the boost thread source code

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I have downloaded the boost code- 1.55.But in this downloaded package I am unable to find the boost thread source code(c++).Where can i download the same? I need below cpp files.

```
barrier.cpp
condition.cpp
exceptions.cpp
mutex.cpp
inline file for mutex.cpp
once.cpp
recursive_mutex.cpp
thread.cpp
inline file for timeconv.cpp
tss.cpp
tss_dll.cpp
tss_hooks.cpp
tss_null.cpp
tss_pe.cpp
xtime.cpp
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/thread

Comment: I am able to find only some files under "boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\libs\thread\src" but not other files.Please help.

Comment: You should be able to use Google to find the Boost source code in less than 30 seconds

Comment: I did download the boost source code and i couldnot find the files i required.That is the reason of my post.

Comment: N.B. using `\\` as a directory separator doesn't make sense in a question tagged [tag:linux]

Answer (score 1):

Look in

```
boost_1_55_0/lib/thread/
```

Note that many files are header-only. Don't assume there **must** be a `barrier.cpp` just because you see a `barrier.hpp`. There isn't one. Because it isn't needed.

See also the BCP Tool:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I am able to find some files under boost_1_55_0\libs\thread\example.Can i use the files from this location?

Comment: I am able to find only some files under "boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\libs\thread\src" but not other files.Please help

Comment: I think you might just be looking for things that don't exist. See update of my answer (sorry that took a while)